# Is there a way to reset offsets of a Kafka consumer group through an API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a use case where there is a consumer group that is consuming messages. I want to build an API to modify its offset. So, when the endpoint is called with the offset I have to change the offset of the consumer group. I am using SpringBoot and the consumer is built using Spring Kafka.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: All of the CLI tools refer to internal Java/Scala classes that can be called directly in code, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Spring for Apache Kafka](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#seek) provides some convenience mechanisms for performing seeks, either during application initialization, or at any time thereafter.

The simplest is to have your listener extend `AbstractConsumerSeekAware` or implement `ConsumerSeekAware`.

Comment: How should I seek based on API? What method should I call to seek to a particular offset? Can you give a code sample, it would be of great help. Thanks

Comment: See the documentation I pointed you to and come back if you have a more specific question; there are several examples in answers on this site; e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66163492/seektotimestamp-in-spring-kafka/66228406#66228406 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59682801/spring-for-kafka-2-3-setting-an-offset-during-runtime-for-specific-listener-with/59684884#59684884 search for `AbstractConsumerSeekAware`.

Answer (score 3):

*This is a solution via **CLI**:*

**List the topics to which the group is subscribed:**

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <kafkahost:port> --group <group_id> --describe
```

Note the values under "CURRENT-OFFSET" and "LOG-END-OFFSET". "CURRENT-OFFSET" is the offset where this consumer group is currently at in each of the partitions.

**Reset the consumer offset for a topic (preview):**

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <kafkahost:port> --group <group_id> --topic <topic_name> --reset-offsets --to-earliest
```

This will print the expected result of the reset, but not actually run it.

**Reset the consumer offset for a topic (execute):**

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <kafkahost:port> --group <group_id> --topic <topic_name> --reset-offsets --to-earliest --execute
```

This will execute the reset and reset the consumer group offset for the specified topic back to 0.

**Repeat 1 to check if the reset is successful**

Comment: A precondition is that the consumer group is _inactive_. If there are active subscribers, these must first be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

To reset an offset, the code has to get the consumer by group id, get started, and stopped. A client has to be created (while consumer is stopped). Once the client has been created, the code has to connect, reset the offset, and then disconnect (as posted below). Once it has reset the consumer group has to be restarted again.

The code below below resets the offset. The key is to get the consumer instance to be able to stop and start the consumers because it cannot reset if a consumer is running. We have this running from the command line which is nice. Hopefully this helps.

```
return kafka.getConsumer( args.groupId )
    .then(consumerInstance => {
        consumer = consumerInstance;
        return consumer.run();
    }).then(()=> {
        return consumer.stop();
    }).then(() => {
         // reset kafka client offset
    })).then(()=> {
        return consumer.run();
    }).

// reset kafka client offset
const { groupId, topic } = args;

const admin = createKafkaClient().admin();

return admin.connect()
    .then(() =>
        admin.resetOffsets({
            groupId,
            topic,
            earliest: true,
    })
    .then(() => admin.disconnect();
```